# Bundle_option_qty not working, with programmatically add bundle product to cart (magento 2.3.2)

Tags: addtocart, controllers, programmatically

I would like to add a bundle product to cart programmatically, however i'm experiencing a problem with the bundle_option_qty.
I can change the selection of the bundle option, however the code is somehow not responding to bundle_option_qty. Please find below my code. in this code you can see the definition of $params, in this array I'm setting the bundle_option_qty with 1=>10 and 2 =>20. So I'm expecting the code to add 10 pieces of bundle_option 1871 and 20 pieces of bundle_option 1873, But it is always adding the default quantity as set in the admin section of the bundle product.

```
 <?php
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Test;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;

class View extends Action
{
    protected $formKey;   
    protected $cart;
    protected $product;
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        FormKey $formKey,
        Cart $cart,
        Product $product) {
            $this->formKey = $formKey;
            $this->cart = $cart;
            $this->product = $product;      
            parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
     { 
     //$aantal =  $this->getRequest()->getParam('aantal');
        $aantal = 1;
       $productId =649;
        $params = array(
                    'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
                    'product' => $productId, 

                    'bundle_option' => [1=>1871,2=>1873],
                    'bundle_option_qty' => [1=>10,2=>20],
                    'qty'   =>$aantal,




                );              
        $product = $this->product->load($productId);       
        $this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);
        $this->cart->save();


     }
}
```

Can anybody help me, by showing what i'm doing wrong or give a different solution of how to add a bundle product with bundle option qty.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample form submission payload when adding a bundle product to cart. Use this as a template to determine your "param".

Here I'm adding 2 products from 2 bundle options:

- 42406 is bundle product ID
- 49 and 82 are ID of bundle-options from catalog_product_bundle_option
- 673 and 1005 are ID of bundle-option-selection from catalog_product_bundle_selection

```
    product: 42406
    form_key: JO4VLFyOpVO96xQs
    bundle_option[49][43498]: 673
    bundle_option_qty[49][43498]: 5
    bundle_option[82][43429]: 1105
    bundle_option_qty[82][43429]: 5
    qty: 1
```